# Display FileName of a Image Python imshow

Tags: python, imshow, imread

Please,

I'm trying to display the filename of a jpeg but i could not find how to.
I want to display the image + the filename of the image.

```
img_dir = "paintings/"
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []
for f1 in files:
    img = imageio.imread(f1)
    data.append(img)

plt.imshow(data[40])
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try [plt.title(filename)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html):